I do not understand what exactly is dynamic memory allocation
So apparently dynamic memory allocation allows memory to be allocated during runtime instead of compile time like static memory allocation. I also understand that using these functions in malloc.h we can save memory by unassigning memory blocks which are not in use by using free(). But my confusion lies in whether the following code comes under dynamic memory allocation or not.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

How is malloc.h functions beneficial in a case where I want the user to specify the size when the above code serves the purpose of allocating during runtime? How are malloc, calloc and realloc different from each other?
Also, what if malloc is being used as follows: (after initialising ptr)
ptr=(int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
How is this different from
int ptr[3];
If the memory required is unknown during writing of the code, can I not declare a pointer and then simply do a ++ to store value in the next memory address as follows?
int* ptr;
while(1){
   scanf("%d",ptr);
   ptr++;
}


int a[n]; is dynamic since it happens at runtime, but it is the same as any automatic variable whose lifetime lasts only until the current block exits.  malloc provides storage which can last beyond the current block.

FYI: Another semi-standard function that allocates dynamic memory is strdup().


But my confusion lies in whether the following code comes under dynamic memory allocation or not.

No, that code does not use “allocated” memory as the C standard specifies it. (Memory for objects is always allocated in one way or another, so this term of the C standard is imprecise. What the C standard calls “allocated” memory is better called “dynamically allocated.”)

Also, what if malloc is being used as follows: ptr=(int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int)); How is this different from int ptr[5];

Well, first, 3 is different from 5.
Second, int ptr[5] inside a function is usually allocated on the hardware stack, and hardware stack space is somewhat limited. We could make stack space very large, and there are mechanisms to request that for your program, but it is kept limited for various reasons, one of which is so that a “runaway” program will be caught before it consumes an inordinate amount of stack space.
Further, with your example using int a[n];, there is no method to detect the user has entered an n that is too large for your hardware stack, other than trying it and having your program crash as a result.
Another major difference is in the lifetime of the objects. For int ptr[5], the memory will be automatically released when the function ends execution. This form of allocating memory cannot be used to return memory to a calling routine. For example, if you have a complicated routine that benefits from having some results of initial calculations stored in a data structure for later use, you cannot allocate the memory for that with int ptr[5] or similar declaration and then return it to the calling routine. With int *p = malloc(5 * sizeof *p);, you can return the memory address to the calling routine, and the memory will remain allocated when your function ends execution.

If the memory required is unknown during writing of the code, can I not declare a pointer and then simply do a ++ to store value in the next memory address as follows?
int* ptr;
while(1){
   scanf("%d",ptr);
   ptr++;
}


No. First, you did not set ptr to any value, so you do not know where it points. Second, if you did set ptr to some address where there was memory available for storing values, you can safely store only as many values as there is memory reserved for. There are multiple things inside your program using memory for different things: The standard input and output streams have buffers. printf has its own workspace. malloc has data structures recording what memory is in use. You cannot just assume you can take some memory address and keeping writing to that address and beyond without running into something else in your process. At some point, in common systems, you will overwrite other data that your program needs or you will run into the end of memory mapped for your process, and a segmentation fault will occur.

How are malloc, calloc and realloc different from each other?

Each of them tries to find available space in your process’ address space, updates the memory management system’s records about which addresses are available for allocation, and returns a pointer to the space allocated for you (or returns a null pointer if space was not available). They also ask the operating system to map more memory into the address space, if needed.
malloc merely provides you the address without making any assurances about what is in that memory.
calloc provides you the address while assuring that the contents of memory was set to zeros.
realloc takes an address of an old memory allocation and provides new space (possibly starting at the same location as the old space). It assures that the contents of the new memory contains a copy of the contents of the old memory, up to the shorter of the two. It provides no assurance about the contents of memory beyond that. (If you pass realloc a null pointer, it attempts to make a new allocation, behaving the same as malloc.)


... my confusion lies in whether the following code comes under dynamic memory allocation or not.

Code with a variable length array (VLA) is using dynamic memory.  It is possibly from a different pool of memory than malloc().


How is malloc.h functions beneficial ...(?)

The return value from malloc() can be check for success/failure.   (VLA) has no standard check.

How are malloc, calloc and realloc different from each other?

malloc() allocates memory that has not certainly been initialized.
calloc() allocates initialized memory with the bit pattern of 0.
ralloc() re-allocates memory.   If the size grows the additional memory is not certainly uninitialized.
For more details, review the C spec or search the web.

ptr=(int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int)); differs from int ptr[5]; in that malloc() failure is detectable.
The first does not declare the object ptr and the 2nd does.
Of course they are for different sizes as 3 != 5.
Using malloc() without a corresponding free() leaks memory.


If the memory required is unknown during writing of the code, can I not declare a pointer and then simply do a ++ to store value in the next memory address as follows?

No. The first iteration of scanf("%d",ptr); passes an uninitialized value in ptr leading to undefined behavior (UB).

Further:
scanf("%d",&n); int a[n]; is poor as it does not check the return value of scanf() nor insure n > 1 nor not too large.
Avoid the form ptr=(int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));.  Allocate based on the size of the object and use ptr = malloc(sizeof ptr[0] * 3);.  It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

Re “Code with a variable length array (VLA) is using dynamic memory”: It is usually implemented with the hardware stack.

@EricPostpischil True.  Further: the amount of memory used in a stack dynamically changes over the life of a typical program.  With various program analysis, this amount is often not determinable at run-time start.  Using VLAs adds to indetermination.  Some implementations (with advanced memory management) will dynamically grow the stack.

In your first example you are trying to get the compiler to allocate space based on an unknown variable. I am not sure which compilers support this, but Microsoft's does not. So you need to use a pointer and a call to malloc in that case:
int* a;
a = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

You can now freely read and write elements a[0] to a[n-1]
If you know the required size at compile time then unless it is a huge number it is best to allocate on the stack with something like:
int ptr[5];

which gives you access to ptr[0] through ptr[4]
Yor last example results in undefined behaviour, which could mean anything from your code appearing to work, to a straight crash. That is because ptr has not been initialised with any space. Declaring a pointer merely tells the compiler how that variable is to be used. But it still needs to be initialised to actually point to some allocated memory space. So you could do the following
int* ptr;
ptr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    ptr[i] = i;
// or
    *ptr = i;
    ptr++; // however you have now destroyed ptr's base address
}

For full details of malloc and its associated functions see Memory allocation

"I am not sure which compilers support this" -- all conforming C99 compilers do (variable-length array support being mandatory in C99), and most compilers conforming to more recent C specifications (where VLA support is optional) also do.  You are correct that Microsoft C does not, but it's unusual in that regard.


So apparently dynamic memory allocation allows memory to be allocated during runtime instead of compile time like static memory allocation.

That's true as far as it goes, but incomplete.  In the first place, it ignores automatic memory allocation (and deallocation), which is what applies to all non-static local variables, including variable-length arrays.  Memory for such variables is assigned and reclaimed at runtime as needed, transparently (for the most part) to the program.  As the term is conventionally used, these are not considered "dynamically allocated".
In the second place, among the features that distinguish dynamically allocated memory is that it remains allocated until explicitly freed.  That's a crucially important feature, as you will understand more fully as your programming journey progresses.

we can save memory by unassigning memory blocks which are not in use by using free().

That's a bit of a glancing blow.  Yes, definitely you can and should free dynamically allocated objects when you have no more use for them.  Yes, that does reduce memory use, which otherwise might become excessive.  But reducing memory usage is not the point of dynamically allocated memory.  [Manual] deallocation is merely a necessary part of using dynamically allocated memory.  The main points of dynamically allocated memory are

ability to obtain objects whose size is determined at runtime,
whose lifetime is not bounded by the execution of any particular block,
and which can fairly easily be (re)allocated to larger or smaller size.


my confusion lies in whether the following code comes under dynamic memory allocation or not.

As the term "dynamic memory allocation" is conventionally used in the context of C, no, there is no dynamic memory allocation in that program.  Specifically, although variable-length arrays such as your a ...

    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];


... have a size determined at runtime, they are still automatically allocated.  You know this quite simply because they are not statically allocated (because they are non-static local variables) and there is no call to a memory-allocation function.

How is malloc.h functions beneficial in a case where I want the user to specify the size when the above code serves the purpose of allocating during runtime?

Variable-length arrays such as you are using are a newbie trap.  They promise the ease of automatic allocation with the benefit of runtime size determination, but in practice,

the amount of memory you can allocate that way is typically much smaller than you can allocate via malloc & co.
if sufficient memory cannot be obtained, or if the requested size is invalid, then there's no way for the program to recover.
once the size is determined, it is fixed.  There's no mechanism for adjusting it.
there are compilers that do not support them.  Microsoft's in particular.

Also, VLAs simply do not serve when you need an object that outlives the function by which it is created.
Dynamic allocation functions are advantageous in all those dimensions.
There are good uses for VLA types that do not run afoul of those issues, but that's a topic for another day.

How are malloc, calloc and realloc different from each other?


they have different signatures
they make different promises about initializing the contents of the allocated space:

malloc does not initialize the space
calloc initializes the space with all bytes 0
realloc initializes part of the space with a copy of the pbject being reallocated, if any, but does not initialize the rest



But the allocated objects obtained via one of these are not inherently distinguishable from those obtained via a different one of them.

Also, what if malloc is being used as follows:
ptr=(int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));

How is this different from
int ptr[5];


Aside from the different sizes, one of those ptrs can be used in almost all the same ways as the other during its lifetime. The main differences are:

when and how each one's lifetime ends -- via a call to free() or realloc(), or automatically when execution of the innermost block containing the declaration terminates.

int ptr[5] declares ptr to be an array.  It can be used like the other ptr because in most contexts array values appearing in expressions are automatically converted to pointers, but there are a couple of exceptions.  The one that you're most likely to run into is their use with the sizeof operator: if ptr is declared as an array then sizeof ptr evaluates to the size of that array, which is the combined size of all its elements, but if ptr is declared as a pointer then sizeof ptr evaluates to the size of a pointer, which is independent of what, if anything, it points to.


Additionally, it is possible for the malloc call to fail. That's unlikely for such a small allocation request, but more likely the larger the requested space is.  This is a feature, not limitation: if automatic allocation cannot be successfully performed then there is no good way for the program to proceed.  Typically it will crash with a stack overflow error or similar.  If malloc() fails, on the other hand, then the program can detect it and try to recover, or at least to shut down more cleanly.

If the memory required is unknown during writing of the code, can I not declare a pointer and then simply do a ++ to store value in the next memory address [...]?

No, you cannot.  Merely declaring a pointer variable does not get you a pointer value for it that points to anything in particular.  One you do assign a valid pointer value, you can write through the pointer to the object to which it points.  You may be able to increment the pointer to point to another writable object, but that is not automatically so.  C does not promise you free access to all of memory, and your OS probably doesn't allow that.  Unless by relying on some kind of external promise, you can safely use a pointer only to access objects that were created according to C semantics (statically, automatically, or dynamically), during those object's lifetimes.
